# Error in Plotting a Time Series in R

Tags: r

I have a time series which goes like this

```
Time,Return
1,1.22 
2,0.95
3,0.25
4,0.25
5,-1.51
```

I wanted to plot a simple time series - time on X axis and return on Y axis

```
dataset <- read.csv("DWDMData.csv",TRUE)
plot(y = dataset$Return,x = dataset$Time,type="1")
```

However, I get an error saying

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type '1'
```

What is the reason for this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?plot` for available plot types.

I'm assuming you want to plot a line graph:

```
plot(x = dataset$Time, y = dataset$Return, type = "l")
```